# How to add a default include path for GCC in Windows?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I am new to C and I'd want to use [JSON-c](https://github.com/json-c/json-c) to parse JSON files I followed the  tutorial in the GitHub readme and the given documentation on the website. Thanks.

Comment: gcc is a commandline compiler , you use the `-I` switch to set include directories. Read the gcc manual

Comment: Thanks for your help it works. I created an include folder in the root directory of my main.c file and add all of  the files in that dir thanks

Comment: You say you followed the tutorial and the documentation. What went wrong and how?